# Android - Horizontally Scrolling Activities

Tags: android, android-activity, swipe

I have some activities and I would like to be able to switch between them by swiping. Is this possible? I was told to use Fragments, but I 've seen it working in 2.x apps. Is it implemented with Gallery or Tabs ?

Thanks.

Comment: It's ok, I found relative information in SO -- thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the view pager for horizontally views.
Example
 http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/537